# why my select helper with class: "form-control" is not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi There I am using rails select helper in embedded ruby `<%= form.select :pay_week, weeks, :selected => currentweek%>` however when I pass utility class "form-control" as second option  `<%= form.select :pay_week, weeks, :selected => currentweek, {include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control"}%>` I end up with "Encountered a syntax error while rendering template". Could anyone explain what I do wrong here?
thanks

Comment: why do you have it in `{}`?

Comment: Its due to `:selected => currentweek` not passed as Hash `{}`. Forms.select's method signature is `select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`. 
The correct way should be `<%= form.select :pay_week, weeks, {selected: currentweek, include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control"}%>`

Comment: good question. My understanding is that I  am passing html class as second option to embedded ruby so it would look similar to this : 'select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})'

Comment: @the_spectator it worked brilliantly. Thanks for your advice